# Css match all children with same class as ancestor

Tags: css, css-selectors

I don't think this is possible, but I'm hoping to be proven wrong.

Given this html:

```
<div class='foo'>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='foo'></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to write a selector to match just the second child div, based on it having the same class as its parent?

**Note**: I know how to write a selector for the second div for this example html, my question is whether you can capture *my class is the same as my parent's class* with some kind of css magic.

Comment: As far as I know, that would require additional logic beyond the normal scope of CSS. I recommend looking into doing this via jQuery.

Comment: @ToddBFisher I can't require javascript in my particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you know the name of the class:

```
.foo .foo {  }
```

> my question is whether you can capture my class is the same as my parent's class with some kind of css magic

**No.** (*Maybe* with [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), but I'm not sure).

Comment: less and sass compile to css, so they have to be <= css in power, right? Or do you mean running less/sass inside a javascript interpreter (I'm using sass, but precompiled)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `<= css in power`... Anyway, I don't mean running them inside a js interpreter. I said "maybe" because I never really used less and sass, so I don't know for sure what can be done and what can't.

Comment: I mean that they both compile to css files (the browser can only parse css, it can't parse less or sass) so their expressiveness must be <= that of css. There's a separate (I think, I've never used it) way to run them where you load sass or less files from javascript code, which would give the potential for features you can't do in css.

Comment: @spike: Don't know about interpreting them with JavaScript, but what you said about "their expressiveness must be <= that of CSS" is correct. However it doesn't preclude having some sort of `@class > @class` syntax that would compile to a big bunch of rules, which would basically be the same as hardcoding CSS. (I hope that wasn't confusing...)

Comment: @BoltClock yup, that's what I meant.

Comment: @spike When I mentioned them, I was thinking of something like `@class > @class` as BoltClock said. I know their compiled output is just regular CSS (and as expressive as CSS), but if you can do `@class > @class` it could save you some time.

Comment: Ah, I see, and it would be cool to be able to define a rule e.g., @prefix-[0-100] and get prefix-1, prefix-2, etc. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.foo { display: block; width: 300px; background: #eee; float: left; margin-right: 50px; }
.foo .bar { display: block; width: 300px; height: 100px; background: #ccc; float: left; }
.foo .foo { display: block; width: 300px; height: 100px; background: #ddd; float: left; }

.foo > .foo:nth-child(2) { color: red; }
</style>

<div class='foo'>
  <div class='bar'>A 1</div>
  <div class='foo'>A 2</div>
  <div class='bar'>A 3</div>
  <div class='foo'>A 4</div>
</div>

<div class='foo'>
  <div class='bar'>B 1</div>
  <div class='foo'>B 2</div>
  <div class='foo'>B 3</div>
  <div class='foo'>B 4</div>
</div>

<div class='foo'>
  <div class='foo'>C 1</div>
  <div class='bar'>C 2</div>
  <div class='bar'>C 3</div>
  <div class='foo'>C 4</div>
</div>
```

[Example (image)](http://s13.postimage.org/h5insnzuu/New_Bitmap_Image.jpg)

[nth child CSS3 property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Comment: @Edward Ruchevits I think you're missing the crux of my question. I don't want to require hardcoding `foo` in my css.

Comment: @spike Oh, then it is impossible, as previously said. :)